# How to display 2 digit integer in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

i was wondering how to display 2 digit decimal number in flutter, for example i want to display timer started by 0 and +1 every seconds but instead of showing "0", "1".."11", i want to make it show like this "00", "01".."11" or even like this "00:00", "00:01".."00:11". I've been looking for a way but can't find it, So maybe you guys can help? Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  sprintf: "^4.0.0"
```

Next:

```
import 'package:sprintf/sprintf.dart';

main() {
  print(sprintf("%02i:%02i",[1,2]));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in case if you don't use any package

```
var number = 5;
var a = number.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
print(a);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. it does what required with stock Dart.